# How to SET LINESIZE ORACLE with echo

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

Hello dear stackoverflowers,

I am writing a shell script in which I need to dump a sqlplus database content in a file, I need to have it done in one command line.

```
echo 'SET LINESIZE  1000; select * from myDb;'| sqlplus -S user/pass@host
```

But I get

> SP2-0268: linesize option not a valid number

I tried without '`;`' but I have the same result.

I couldn't find any example here or elsewhere on how to do this.

Any help on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'SET LINESIZE  1000\n select * from myDb;' |sed 's/\\n/\n/' |sqlplus -S user/pass@host
```

Comment: You might also consider using here strings:

    cat<<EOT
    yay!
    here!
    EOT